# Access values of variables set on runtime

Tags: java, oop

Here's the scenario :

I have 3 classes Class A,Class B and Class C.Now I am calling a method defined in C with return type String in Class A. I am setting the return value to another String in Class A. Now in class B i am making an object of Class A and calling the String set in A using the object. IF you want to know the execution then first i am calling the method defined in C in a and then the String in B. But i am getting the string value a NULL in Class B.

Class C

```
Class C{
 //method with return type as string
 public String getString(){
    return "Some String Here";
  }
}
```

Class A

```
Class A{
public String s;
public void somemethod(){
C obj = new C();
s= obj.getString();
  }
}
```

Class B

```
Class B(){
pubic void anothermethod(){
A obj = new A();
String ss = obj.s;
}
}
```

ss when printed gives null as its value. When I print s I get the correct string. Here's how i am calling from main class

1. Method somemethod() from Class A

2.Then Method anothermethod() from Class B.

Sorry if my question is a bit noobish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is regarding how you're getting the null in `ss`, you never called `somemethod`on `obj` in `anothermethod`. Everytime you call `anothermethod`, you instantiate a new `A`, in which the String field `s` has never been initialized and is still null.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Sorry for my noobish doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version. See comments:

```
class A{

    private C c;
    public void somemethod(){
        c = new C();//better put is A constructor 
    }
    public String getS() {
        return c.getString();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new B().anothermethod();
    }
}

class B{

    public void anothermethod(){
        A a = new A(); //better put is B constructor 
        a.somemethod();
        System.out.println( a.getS()); //output: Some String Here
    }
}

class C{

    //method with return type as string
    public String getString(){
        return "Some String Here";
    }
}
```